# Spring-Boot is not working with Flyway

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I am using Spring-Boot v1.1.10.RELEASE for my spring based web application. My DB is Postgres & used Flyway for my DB migration.

The postgres sql script file is successfully executed by **flyway-maven-plugin** by the following maven command i.e. ***mvn compile flyway:migrate***

But the same Postgres sql script file is throwing **PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations** error when running through the **Spring-Boot** *Application.java* file.

**NOTE:** From spring-boot I am executing the script file on fresh DB i.e. at least there is no SCHEMA_VERSION table in DB.

Any inputs?

Thanks,
Baji

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring Boot 1.1 uses Flyway 3.0 which does not support `COPY FROM STDIN`. Support [was added](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/commit/7b9b2d141cb9ff63f6ec01baec2e46f519b19ee4) in 3.1. You can either upgrade to Spring Boot 1.2 (which uses Flyway 3.1 by default) or stick with Spring Boot 1.1 and try overriding the version of Flyway to 3.1.